# H2 limit and offset, is there a guarantee on ordering?

Tags: sql, h2

When using LIMIT and OFFSET, what are the guarantees that each such statement will order the input in the same way?
To illustrate:

```
 *price* | *product*
---------------------
  2.99   | party hat green
  2.99   | party hat pink
  3.99   | red ball
  3.99   | blue ball
  3.99   | yellow ball
```

If:

```
SELECT FROM toys ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 3;
```

returns:

```
 *price* | *product*
---------------------
  2.99   | party hat green
  2.99   | party hat pink
  3.99   | red ball
```

Can i be sure the next query:

```
SELECT FROM toys ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3;
```

returns:

```
 *price* | *product*
---------------------
  3.99   | blue ball
  3.99   | yellow ball
```

After all, all three balls have the same price, so any ordering of the three rows is valid.

Comment: You should include a second key in the `order by` so the sort is stable (that is, the keys have no ties).

Comment: @Gordon, so it's up to me to construct the 'order by' so that ordering is defined? I can add an index at creation time for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an `ORDER BY` is present, the database is free to return the equivalent rows (per the ordering criteria) in any order, and this order may change over time.

In your example, if you want the rows in a particular order, just specify it. Maybe:

```
SELECT FROM toys ORDER BY price, product LIMIT 3;
```

When no `ORDER BY` is specified the database will return rows in no specific order. Per SQL definition the database is free to return the rows as it pleases. The order of these rows may change in time as well.